# iOS UIPickerView - Increase height and radius

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

In my app I'd like to use a UIPickerView in order to display a list of things:

I choose a PickerView instead of the TableView for the following reasons:

- I want the user to select the option from the rotating view instead than by clicking on the row
- I want to have the magnifying effect on the selected row
- I like the rotating nature of it
- I want to have the taptic and audio feedback when scrolling the view

The problem is that if I enlarge the PickerView to basically fullscreen, I would only see 4 rows because the wheel's radius is to small.

Is there any way I can increase it in order to see more content in the UIPickerView without scrolling?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share the code you have written to achieve that.

Comment: @Sateesh I just extended the UIPickerView class and given it a constraint height. I couldn't find anything about the radius

Comment: The picker view should extend with the height constraint getting bigger. Do you have enough data to display? Please share your code connected to the picker view.